RuntimeError: probability tensor contains either `inf`, `nan` or element < 0
am trying to output the response of the llama2 model that i installed locally, but when i try to execute the following lines:
output = model.generate(**inputs, streamer=streamer,
use_cache=True, max_new_tokens=float('inf'))
1-I tried model.bfloat16() but didn't work
2-changed  eos_token with unk_token in this line: tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.unk_token
does anyone have any idea how to solve this please?
